# How send REST POST request including strings + photo

Tags: c++, rest, cpprest-sdk

I am using cpprestsdk to create a desktop client for an external API.  I'm stuck on a POST request for registration, in which I need to send strings and a photo.

I plan to make the registry through such a function:
`bool POSTUser(string_t &token, string_t &name, string_t &email, string_t &phone, string_t &photoPath);`

I suppose I will need to use this overload: [web::http::client::http_client::request](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1client_1_1http__client.html#abbdc23648483780a7cc898bbdd306211), because the responses from the server also come in json, and this [filestream](https://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/class_concurrency_1_1streams_1_1file__stream.html) but I have no idea how to cram it json, and what else is _CharType in the template???

Example in the server API documentation:

- name - string
- email - string
- phone - string
- position_id - string
- photo - user photo should be jpg/jpeg image

Example of method url: `https://server.server/api/v1/users`

Example curl sh:

```bash
$curl --form "photo=@example/photo.jpg;" \ --form name=Jhon \ --form email=jhon@example.com \ --form phone=+380955388485 \ --form position_id=2 \ https://server.server/api/v1/users
```

Example javascript:

```js
var formData = new FormData(); // file from input type='file'
var fileField = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
formData.append('position_id', 2);
formData.append('name', 'Jhon');
formData.append('email', 'Jhon@gmail.com');
formData.append('phone', '+380955388485');
formData.append('photo', fileField.files[0]);
fetch('https://server.server/api/v1/users', {
  method: 'POST', body: formData, headers: {
    'Token': token, // get token with GET api/v1/token method 
  },
}).then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if(data.success) { 
    // process success response 
  } else {
    // proccess server errors
  } 
}).catch(function(error) { 
  // proccess network errors
});
```

Comment: Did you try searching on Google? It seems like a common use case, there must be solutions already out there.

Comment: cpprestsdk has a serious problem with examples. If they are, then it is impossible to find them. Google either gives examples in other APIs, or just in other languages

Comment: That SDK is now in maintenance mode. They don't recommend using it in new projects. Better to switch to newer frameworks. I know a few other frameworks, have a look at CrowCpp or Pistache. Not sure why you need a framework for the client. Maybe you can simply use Postman. Also, there is [libcpr](https://github.com/libcpr/cpr)

Comment: Yes, maybe I will choose another API